# How to display onboard keyboard for one language only?

Tags: keyboard, input-language, onscreen-keyboard

I use two languages: English and Arabic. I would like to display the onscreen keyboard when using Arabic, but not English. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Your Ununtu version??

Comment: Latest version, 20.10